# Operations on the class of linear orderings from a categorical perspective

Tags: category-theory

Delaying the question for now, I will henceforth use $\mathcal{L}$ to represent the class of **(strict) linear orderings** and elements of $\mathcal{L}$ will be denoted using lowercase Greek letters (possibly subscripted) from $\alpha$ to $\epsilon$.  I will refer to the category whose object class is $\mathcal{L}$ as $\mathbf{Lin}$ where $\mathrm{Mor(\mathbf{Lin})}$ consists of all isotone maps i.e. maps $f\colon\alpha\to\beta$ such that
\begin{equation}
a<b\quad\Longrightarrow\quad f(a)\leq f(b).
\end{equation}

The three operations I wish to inquire about will now be defined.  If $\alpha,\beta,\alpha_i\in\mathcal{L}$, with respective universes $A,B,A_i$, for each $i\in B$ then:

1. $\alpha+\beta$ is inverse (of the) lexicographical ordering on $(A\times\{0\})\cup (B\times\{1\})$ (intuitively: the concatenation of $\alpha$ and $\beta$)
2. $\sum_{\gamma\in\beta}\alpha_i$ is (analogously to (1.)) the inverse lexicographical ordering (w.r.t. $\beta$) of $\bigcup_{i\in\beta}(A_i\times\{i\})$ (intuitively: one takes $\beta$ and then substitutes each point $i\in B$ with $\alpha_i$).
3. The product is defined $\alpha\cdot\beta=\sum_{i\in\beta}\alpha$ (informally: $\beta$ copies of $\alpha$).

I am a novice when it comes to the theory of categories but essentially I'm hoping to see if the above operations can be extended to related structures (e.g. semi-linear orderings a.k.a trees) using their categorical descriptions (given they exist) as a guide.

**The question** is thus how can we relate (if at all possible), within $\mathbf{Lin}$, each of these constructions (operations) to their constituents (arguments/operands) using categorical language.  It would be appreciated if *as far possible, only concepts encountered within a first course in category theory* are utilised in the answer (I hope this is not asking too much).

Comment: Kindly let me know if there are any mistakes in my exposition or question.  I was quite tired when writing it and am certain there might be some.  Hopefully the overall picture and my question itself are clear regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can indeed express these concepts categorically, although it's pretty messy. *(For simplicity I'll conflate isomorphic linear orders.)*

The key point is that we can "see" the structure of an object in **Lin** in a purely categorical way, and so the order-theoretic definitions wind up with purely categorical rephrasings.

---

The first thing to do is dig into the internal structure of linear orders in a purely categorical manner. First, we observe that **Lin** has a terminal object (the one-element linear order $\bf 1$), and elements of a linear order $L$ correspond exactly to morphisms from $\bf 1$ to $L$. This also lets us identify *injective* and *surjective* morphisms:

- $i:L_1\rightarrow L_2$ is injective iff there are no distinct morphisms $m_1,m_2:{\bf 1}\rightarrow L_2$ such that $im_1=im_2$.
- $i:L_1\rightarrow L_2$ is surjective iff for every $m:{\bf 1}\rightarrow L_2$ there is some $n:{\bf 1}\rightarrow L_1$ such that $in=m$.

*(In fact, unsurprisingly injectivity and surjectivity correspond to monicity and epicity. But I'm going to use the terms injective/surjective to emphasize the success we've had pinning down the more set theoretic operations.)*

---

The next step is to recover the linear order structure - that is, we want a purely categorical way to compare morphisms ${\bf 1}\rightarrow L$ (for each $L$) which recovers the linear order structure. Let ${\bf 2}$ be the linear order with two elements, let $a:{\bf 1}\rightarrow{\bf 2}$ be the morphism corresponding to the least element of $\bf 2$, and let $z:{\bf 1}\rightarrow {\bf 2}$ be the morphism corresponding to the greatest element of ${\bf 2}$. Then given any $L\in \mathcal{L}$ and morphisms $p_1,p_2:{\bf 1}\rightarrow L$, we say $p_1\le p_2$ iff $p_1=p_2$ or there is a morphism $q:L\rightarrow {\bf 2}$ such that $qp_1=a$ and $qp_2=z$. Similarly, we'll say $p_1<p_2$ if $p_1\le p_2$ and $p_1\not=p_2$.

We can also compare more general morphisms: given $a_1\in Hom(L_1, L_3)$ and $a_2\in Hom(L_2,L_3)$ we say $a_1<a_2$ if for every $c_1\in Hom({\bf 1}, L_1), c_2\in Hom({\bf 1}, L_2)$ we have $a_1c_1<a_2c_2$.

---

At this point we can define sums of linear orders: given linear orders $L_1, L_2,L_3$, we have that $L_3\cong L_1+L_2$ iff there are morphisms $m_1:L_1\rightarrow L_3$, $m_2:L_2\rightarrow L_3$ such that:

- $m_1$ and $m_2$ are injective.
- For every $k:{\bf 1}\rightarrow L_3$ there is an $n:{\bf 1}\rightarrow L_i$ with $m_in=k$ for some $i\in\{1,2\}$. **(Covering)**
- $m_1<m_2$. **(Ordering)**

This leaves the problem of indexed sums. But the idea is basically the same: given a linear order $I$ and a family of linear orders $\{L_i: i\in Hom({\bf 1}, I)\}$, the key property of the indexed sum $S$ is the existence of a family of injective morphisms $m_i: L_i\rightarrow S$ satisfying the appropriate analogues of **(Covering)** and **(Ordering)** above.

Comment: Would you happen to know of a categorical version Feferman-Vaught theorem?  Also, if you don't mind me asking, are there any applications of category theory to (mostly first-order) model theory or does it enlighten us anyway?  A simple one might be if in the category of models and elementary embeddings of a theory T it is true that every morphism is a (split/regular/extremal/strong) monic?  Are these categories of models balanced? etc. etc.

Comment: @Jean-PierredeVilliers This is all outside of my comfort zone - I don't really know much category theory at all. That said, I do know that there are definitely important interactions between the two - e.g. we can develop some of classical model theory inside topoi [very different from **Sets**](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~nate/papers/published/201x/2011/number%20of%20countable%20models%20in%20realizability%20topos/preprint.pdf) with interesting results - I'm just not qualified to say much about them.

Comment: I recall a MSE or MO question about applications of category theory to model theory, but I can't find it right now; if it wouldn't be a duplicate it would certainly be a good question.